# Eclipse/Glassfish running out of memory

Tags: eclipse, glassfish

I'm developing a web app using Eclipse/Glassfish on Windows 7, and I see this error at least a few times a day when deploying a new version of the app:

```
SEVERE: Exception while preparing the app : PermGen space
SEVERE: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

When I see it, I have to close Eclipse, use the Windows Task Manager to stop a Java process (which I suspect is Glassfish), and re-start Eclipse.  It's a nuisance, and an unwelcome interruption.

Is there anything I can fix/configure that would make this error go away, or at least decrease its frequency?  Or is this a memory leak I'm just going to have to live with?

Comment: I think I've seen "hot" redeploys of Spring/Hibernate apps leak memory over time. If you're using those two I'm not sure whether anything can be done with it. That said I admit this is a vague guess based on a recollection from a while ago.

Comment: In the directory from where you run Eclipse, you have a file eclipse.ini   Does it contain any settings for the MaxPermSize? If not, you can try adding: --launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M ... or some other number and seeing if something other than the default works better for you. See this link: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: @Darius:  Thank you, I'll give that a try.  Out of curiosity, do you know of any resources discussing the largest settings that should be considered?  I have a pretty decent machine, and Eclipse/Glassfish are probably the most important applications running on it at any given time; I have no problem letting them hog resources.

Comment: These are really JVM settings (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a memory leak in Sun / Oracle JVM <= 7 which often occurs when using JPA. Upgrading to [Oracle's JVM 8 should solve this](http://karunsubramanian.com/websphere/one-important-change-in-memory-management-in-java-8/).

If you're bound to JVM 7 or lower, you can add the following VM arguments to Glassfish's launch configuration in Eclipse to increase the memory limit (in this example to 1024 MB), which makes the OOMs less regular:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024M
```